# Finding coordinates of a point in OpenLayers

Tags: gis, openlayers

How can one get the coordinates of a particular point on a map in OpenLayers?

Comment: Do you mean getting the coordinates of the point where the user clicked? Or showing the coordinates of the cursor when moving it over the map?

Comment: yes, but I want to get all the coordinates of the previously marked points on the same map. Is it possible? 
I'm implementing a crime mapping system. For that I need that functionality. thanks.

Comment: What you mean as "previously marked points"? I think you need to be more specific and describe complete user's interaction flow, otherwise it will be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Handle click event on map [Click](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Click-js.html) handler. Here is [one](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GET-mouse-position-td3955090.html) of [many](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Get-lat-lon-from-user-click-td3896587.html) sample codes you can find in OpenLayers mailing list archives:

```
map.events.register('click', map, handleMapClick);

function handleMapClick(e)
{
   var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
   // use lonlat

   // If you are using OpenStreetMap (etc) tiles and want to convert back 
   // to gps coords add the following line :-
   // lonlat.transform( map.projection,map.displayProjection);

   // Longitude = lonlat.lon
   // Latitude  = lonlat.lat
}
```

Comment: @mloskot Should be map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy); no?

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function init(){
      map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
      base_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
      "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
      map.addLayer(base_layer);
      map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      map.events.register('click', map, handleMapClick);
    } 

    function handleMapClick(evt)
    {
       var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(evt.xy);
       // use lonlat
       alert(lonlat);
    } 
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
  Hello Map.<br />
 <div id="map"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

@mloskot Your answer is great you had a mistake with the evt variable.

Just added the html markup to make it a working page.